# AWS pandas installation giving ERROR: virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: python, c++, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install pandas on AWS EC2 instance, t2.micro RAM size 1GB, but it is throwing an error in the middle

```
 > from pandas/_libs/join.c:435:
    >     /usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_deprecated_api.h:11:2:
    > warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining
    > NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
    >      #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by #defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"
    >       ^
    >     virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
    >     error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    >     
    >     ----------------------------------------
    >     Command "/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-XJKxj6/pandas/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
    > 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__,
    > 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-QLWuWh-record/install-record.txt
    > --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-XJKxj6/pandas
```

What could be the problem? Is it the problem with t2.micro ?

How much memory does pandas installation takes?

Comment: yes it is your micro instance. Try upgrading to small instance and it should work fine.

Comment: Same problem here. Did it work by moving to a larger instance? Or was the problem different?

Comment: Yes. I increased the instance size to small. then it worked.

Comment: Why Pandas require >1GB ram to install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the instance size micro. I increased the instance size to small then it worked for me.